# Can't understand why Zend_Mail::addHeader() strips newlines

Tags: php, zend-framework, smtp, mime, zend-mail

*(Since this is my first SO question, let me just say I hope it's not too Zend-specific. As far as I can tell this shouldn't be a problem. Although I could have posted it in a Zend-specific forum, I feel like I'm at least as likely to get a good answer here, especially since the answer might involve MIME-related issues that transcend Zend Framework. I'm basically trying to understand whether the issue I'm facing should be considered a ZF bug, or if I'm misunderstanding something or misusing it.)*

I've been using Zend_Mail to build up a MIME message that gets sent through SendGrid, an email distribution service. Their platform allows you to send emails through their SMTP server, but gives added features when you use a special header (X-SMTPAPI) whose value is a JSON-encoded string of proprietary parameters, which can get quite long.

Eventually, the header I was passing got too long (I think >1000 chars), and I got errors. I was confused because I knew that it was getting passed through PHP's native wordwrap() function before I passed the value to Zend_Mail::addHeader(), so I thought line length should never be a problem.

It turns out that addHeader() strips newlines very deliberately, and with no particular explanation by way of comments.

```
// In Zend_Mail::addHeader()
$value = $this->_filterOther($value);


// In Zend_Mail::_filterOther()
$rule = array("\r" => '',
              "\n" => '',
              "\t" => '',
);
return strtr($data, $rule);
```

Ok, this seemed reasonable at first -- maybe ZF wants full control of formatting and line-wrapping. The next method called in Zend_Mail::addHeader() is

```
$value = $this->_encodeHeader($value);
```

This method encodes the value (either quoted-printable or base64 as appropriate) and chunks it into lines of appropriate length, but *only* if it contains "non-printable characters", as determined by Zend_Mime::isPrintable($value).

Looking into that method, newlines (\n) are indeed considered non-printable characters! So if only they hadn't been stripped out of the string in the previous method call, the long header would get encoded as QP and chunked into 72-char lines, and everything would work fine. In fact, I did a test where I commented out the call to _filterOther(), and the long header gets encoded and goes through with no problem. But now I've just made a careless hack to ZF without really understanding the purpose behind the line I removed, so this can't be a long-term solution.

My medium-term solution has been to extend Zend_Mail and create a new method, addHeaderForceEncode(), which will always encode the value of the header, and thus always chunk it into short lines. But I'm still not satisfied because I don't understand why that _filterOther() call was necessary in the first place -- maybe I shouldn't be working around it at all.

Can anyone explain to me why this behaviour exists of stripping newlines? It seems to inevitably lead to situations where a header can get too long if it doesn't contain any "non-printable characters" other than newlines.

I've done a bunch of different searches on this subject and looked through some ZF bug reports, but haven't seen anyone talking about this. Surprisingly it seems to be a really obscure issue. FYI I'm working with ZF 1.11.11.

---

**Update:** In case anyone wants to follow the ZF issue I opened about this, here it is: [Zend_Mail::addHeader() UNfolds long headers, then throws exception](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11977)

Comment: StackOverflow can answer everything ;)

+1 For your first question here.

Comment: Thanks for making me feel welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably running into a few things.  Per [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt), text lines in SMTP can't exceed 1000 characters:

> text line
>
> The maximum total length of a text line including the  is
>   1000 characters (not counting the leading dot duplicated for
>   transparency).  This number may be increased by the use of SMTP
>   Service Extensions.

A header can't contain newlines, so that's probably why Zend is stripping them.  For long headers, it's common to insert a line break (CRLF in SMTP) and a tab to "wrap" them.

Excerpt from [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt):

> Each header field can be viewed as a single, logical  line  of
>   ASCII  characters,  comprising  a field-name and a field-body.
>   For convenience, the field-body  portion  of  this  conceptual
>   entity  can be split into a multiple-line representation; this
>   is called "folding".  The general rule is that wherever  there
>   may  be  linear-white-space  (NOT  simply  LWSP-chars), a CRLF
>   immediately followed by AT LEAST one LWSP-char may instead  be
>   inserted.

I would say that the `_encodeHeader()` function should possibly look at line length, and if the header is longer than some magic value, do the "wrap and tab" to have it span multiple lines.

Comment: I checked as well and it doesn't appear Zend_Mail supports header folding, nor does it give you a way to add a "raw header" that it doesn't process.  It appears this modification would best be made in the `_prepareHeaders` method of `Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract`.  If you pass the third parameter `$append` to `addHeader`, it will fold the appended data, but also adds a comma at the end of the line which I think would break your JSON.  This could be worthy of creating an [issue](http://framework.zend.com/issues/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: @tomlogic I don't understand why you said "A header can't contain newlines, so that's probably why Zend is stripping them", since newlines as part of CRLF are necessary for folding (as you also pointed out via RFC 822). But in general I take it you agree that there's some awareness missing from addHeader() or _encodeHeader()?

Comment: @LinusR: I think that Zend isn't expecting a folded header, and that's why it's stripping the newlines.  In my opinion, Zend should either accept a folded header (where each CRLF is followed by whitespace; no bare CR or LF) or try to fold long headers.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your thoughts. I'll open an issue on ZF's tracker.